# Exercise about extensions of fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field and let $t$ be a transcendental element over $k$. Write $k(t)$ for the field
generated by $t$ over $k$. Show that for every $r ∈ k(t)$, $r \notin k$, we have that $t$ is algebraic over $k(r)$ and that $r$ is transcendental over $k$.

$r$ can be written as $\frac f g$, for $f(t),g(t)\in k[t]$. Then $h(x)=rg(x)-f(x)$ is a polynomial in $k(r)[x]$ with $t$ as a solution. To prove that $r$ is trascendental over $k$, notice that if it wasn't true then $k\subset k(r)\subset k(t)$ would be all algebraic extensions and we would have $t$ algebraic over $k$. Is it ok or did I miss to check something?

I also had to prove that for every field $K\subset k(t)$, such that $k\subseteq K$ is algebraic, actually $k=K$. Since any $a\in K\setminus k$ belongs to $k(t)\setminus k$, $a$ is trascendental over $k$, showing that if $K$ is algebraic $K=k$.

Comment: hi Carlos; you need to verify that $h(x)$ is not the zero polynomial for your first argument to go through. as a hint, notice that you didn't use the hypothesis that $r\notin k$ at all.. besides this everything looks good to me!

Comment: Thank you, I would use this argument for the part that I forgot: if $h(x)=0$ we have that $rg(x)$ is a polynomial in $k[x]$. So if $b\in k$ is anyone of the coefficients of $g(x)$, we have that $br\in k$, implying $r\in k$ that is contradictory.

Comment: dear Carlos, yep, that is exactly right! :)